# WtpDownload_linux: Usage, gathering the required files?

Tags: embedded, arm

Edit: These tags were removed as they don't exist: ESPRESSObin U-Boot marvell A3700

I'm in over my head working on an ESPRESSObin. I flashed the wrong bootloader, because I thought the recovery was simple and easy... and I figured a few bytes for version checking incoming blobs wasn't ludicracy. Now I find I need a handful of files and it's not really clear what repos they come from.

One thing is that I just don't have a MS(tm)Windows machine, another is that I'm using a PI Zero for talking to the serial port.

Where am I supposed to get and am I supposed to use `WtpDownload_linux`:

- `NTIM.bin`/`TIM.bin`
- `<Image>_h.bin`

Answer (score 0):

The main stumbling block for me was that there is only a few second window to stop the boot process after the ~4min wtp download.  So you really have to watch the timer count down closely.

I don't know if this is still up, but I found the images here:
https://forum.0cd.xyz/t/espressobin-downloads/512

I'm choosing to flash u-boot from here:
http://dotsrc.dl.osdn.net/armbian-dl/espressobin/u-boot/

```
SHA256 (Downloads/flash-image-ddr4-1g-1cs-1000_800.bin) = e3a9d9605d5a9ad1ff848985c18b1ce41c2dddfffcc8f8364f2d57d833e652bb
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat bin/uart-save.sh 
#!/bin/sh
exec WtpDownload_linux -V -P UART -C ${1:-0} \
    -B ~/uart-recovery-2018.03-armada-18.12-ddr4_1sc_1g/TIM_ATF.bin \
    -I ~/uart-recovery-2018.03-armada-18.12-ddr4_1sc_1g/wtmi_h.bin \
    -I ~/uart-recovery-2018.03-armada-18.12-ddr4_1sc_1g/boot-image_h.bin -E
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd ~/uart-recovery-2018.03-armada-18.12-ddr4_1sc_1g
pi@raspberrypi:~/uart-recovery-2018.03-armada-18.12-ddr4_1sc_1g $ sha256sum --tag *
SHA256 (atf-ntim.txt) = c68c65c985f1f3e42749ad6937eecae0d4b5aaa045752a451149b70770aed65f
SHA256 (boot-image_h.bin) = eb923506af435f5923634d85e77f4fb047e919d2d5bc691c1ce809bb8de7bed6
SHA256 (TIM_ATF.bin) = 9b4ab95bc2a6d282590fbfcd18f3c8955b8d69dbfa9a16cc5987417f17849676
SHA256 (wtmi_h.bin) = 6d018999b472d822a8c54b817d67c1f4e20d22ab5c036a0854ea9fa8a591afeb
```

`${1:-0}` is a little bit of shell code that defaults to `/dev/ttyUSB0`, but allows something like `uart-save.sh 1` to use ...`USB1` instead.  AFAICT `atf-ntim.txt` is not used for anything.

Then as a first step run `env default -a`(or similar) prior to trying to bubt, as any corruption here could cost you.  I used the spi destination, FWIW.

The instructions for Linux are missing a step shown for Windows.  They enter `wrt\r`, where `\r` is just the serial port version of `\n` all the terminal programs should convert 4 u.  What I experienced was that the linux downloader would run off and try and boot, falling back to rebooting after only 2 seconds.  I had to quicly hit enter a few times to get the `Marvell>>` prompt.

Speaking of witch have u tried `cu` it's spiffy for tasks like this: `cu --line /dev/ttyUSB0 --speed 115200 --nostop --nortscts`, use `\n~.` to exit... or `\n~~.` if you are running `ssh -t cu` or similar.